# how to acces the textfield value created manually from a Click on Button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i am doing sample application where i am  creating two TextField programitically i.e,Textfield1 and Textfield2 and Having one Button which is Dragged on UI.

Now My requirement is I have two textfield  created manually and a Button, When i click a button it should access the value entered in both  textfield and display its value on console using NSLog.

so can anyone suggest me how to do it?As textifeild is created programmitically it is not having IBOutlet. so i want to read textfield  value  when i click button and display on Console.so please suggest me with sample code

```
{
[self Textfiled1];
[Self TextField2];
```

}

```
-(void)textField1
```

{

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 250, 200, 35)];
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = TRUE;
[textField addTarget:self 
              action:@selector(textFieldDone:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];     
[self.view addSubview:textField];
[textField release];
```

}

Same as above for Textfield2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `tag` for both the UITextField.

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 250, 200, 35)];
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
textField.tag = 1;
...
```

for the second,

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 250, 200, 35)];
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
textField.tag = 2;
...
```

In Button click action method,

```
UITextField *textField = (UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
NSString *text1 = textField.text;
```

Similarly for the next UITextField.

Answer (score 0):

Set the text field' s tag property before adding it and get the text field back using it.

```
textField.tag = 1;

UITextField* tf1 = (UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are adding textfield to self.view use the tag like below.

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 250, 200, 35)];
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = TRUE;
[textField addTarget:self 
              action:@selector(textFieldDone:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];     
    textField.tag = 3;
[self.view addSubview:textField];
[textField release];
```

whenever you need it then do like this.

```
UITextField *tex = [self.view viewWithTag:3];
NSLog(@"%@",tex.text);
```